# MySQL LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have a table `cars(id, name)` containing 20 rows. The other table `carLog(username, car, count)` contains rows which count the cars a player has bought (if there is no row if they haven't bought the car)

I want my query to return all twenty cars, and the extra join info, if they've got a row in the `carLog` table but I can't get it to work.

```
SELECT * FROM cars LEFT JOIN carLog ON cars.id=carLog.car
```

This is returning hundreds of rows, I want it to return 20 rows (one for each car), and the extra info in the row if the username has purchased the car:

```
WHERE carLog.username='Juddling'
```

I have no idea if I'm meant to be using GROUP BY, WHERE or another type of join!

Comment: In MS SQL you can do top 20 in MySQL I think it's limit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the username condition from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN carLog
  ON cars.id=carLog.car
     AND carLog.username='Juddling'
```

The WHERE clause is applied when the JOIN is already completed. This means, it will discard the NULL rows that the LEFT JOIN added.

Answer (score 1):

As you are limiting the table from the outer join, you have to put the condition in the `on`, not the `where`:

```
select * from cars
left join carLog on cars.id = carLog.car and carlog.username = 'Juddling'
```