# Joining table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am developing a business review system.
`business` table is-

```
id     category
1         1
2         1
3         1
4         2
```

`review` table is -

```
id     bid     reviewer_point
1       1             4
2       1             3
3       2             4
4       2             5
```

I need to return the `10` `business ID`'s of the top rated (based on rating point average) business filtered by `category`.

So far i could find the average of the rating of each business.

```
SELECT business.category, bid, 
     COUNT(*) AS review_count, AVG(reviewer_point) AS average_points 
FROM reviews 
GROUP BY bid    
ORDER BY average_points DESC WHERE category = 1 LIMIT 10;
```

I am unable to use `WHERE` clause.  How can i get my preferred solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you use `WHERE`?

Comment: Because cant fetch `category` . Sql error shows `Unknown column 'business.category' in 'field list'`

Comment: That's because you are missing the `JOIN` part of the query. Have a look into the documentation if you are in doubt: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL LEFT JOIN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438392/mysql-left-join)

Answer (score 2):

The order in a mysql single query is:

```
1st SELECT;
2nd FROM;
3rd WHERE;
4th GROUP BY;
5th HAVING;
6th ORDER BY;
7th LIMIT.
```

Try put each with a break line.

Answer (score 1):

The WHERE clause has to come before the GROUP BY

```
SELECT business.category, bid, 
     COUNT(*) AS review_count, AVG(reviewer_point) AS average_points 
FROM review
WHERE category = 1 
GROUP BY bid    
ORDER BY average_points DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

However, this still won't work as the `business` table hasn't been joined in this query. I'd include this but there's no obvious way to join `business` to `review`. Should the `review` table have a column containing a reference to `business.id`?

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a287/5)

Best of luck.

### EDIT

With the information supplied in a comment (below) by OP the revised query becomes

```
SELECT b.category, r.bid, 
     COUNT(*) AS review_count, AVG(reviewer_point) AS average_points 
FROM review r
INNER JOIN business b
  ON b.id = r.bid
WHERE b.category = 1 
GROUP BY r.bid, b.category
ORDER BY average_points DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

and [the updated SQLFiddle can be found here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a287/6)

Comment: `bid` of `reviews` is the reference column for `id` of `business`.

Comment: Can you please expand with joining `business`?