# Joining two tables with date ranges

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have two SQL tables that contain start and end dates.

```
 Table 1: Name, AddedDate
 Table 2: Name, RemovedDate
```

I'm am looking to join these two tables and dump the data into a temp table to show when a name was added and removed from a list.

> **The same name may have been added and removed multiple times.**

Desired Output Example

```
- Name, AddedDate, RemovedDate
- Jane, 2017-02-01, 2017-02-03
- Bill, 2017-01-28, (blank)
- Mike, 2017-01-15, 2017-01-19
- Jane, 2017-01-13, 2017-01-14
```

Can someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL LEFT JOIN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438392/mysql-left-join)

Answer (score 3):

Another option is an **OUTER APPLY** (If SQL Server)

**Example**

```
Declare @Table1 table (Name varchar(25),AddedDate date)
Insert Into @Table1 Values
('Jane', '2017-02-01'),
('Bill', '2017-01-28'),
('Mike', '2017-01-15'),
('Jane', '2017-01-13')

Declare @Table2 table (Name varchar(25),RemovedDate date)
Insert Into @Table2 Values
('Jane', '2017-02-03'),
('Mike', '2017-01-19'),
('Jane', '2017-01-14')


Select A.Name
      ,A.AddedDate
      ,B.RemovedDate
 From  @Table1 A
 Outer Apply (
                Select RemovedDate=min(RemovedDate)
                 From  @Table2
                 Where Name=A.Name
                  and  RemovedDate>=A.AddedDate
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Name    AddedDate   RemovedDate
Jane    2017-02-01  2017-02-03
Bill    2017-01-28  NULL
Mike    2017-01-15  2017-01-19
Jane    2017-01-13  2017-01-14
```

Comment: Nice job deriving the input from the output. +1

Comment: @SqlZim Pretty much mastered Copy-and-Paste.  After all, I'm a coder  :)

Comment: @CST1126 Happy it helped

Comment: @CST1126 Just in case. the OUTER APPLY will include null values while a CROSS APPLY will excluded them  i.e. Bill

Answer (score 1):

Using correlated subquery to consider only the last time the name was added (and potentially removed)...

```
select Name,
       AddedDate,
      (select max(RemovedDate)
         from table_2
        where Name=q1.Name
          and RemovedDate >= q1.AddedDate) as RemovedDate
 from (select Name,
              max(AddedDate) as AddedDate
         from table_1
        group by name) as q1
order by AddedDate desc,
         Name;
```

Same correlated subquery approach to show every time a name was added and removed...

```
select Name,
       AddedDate,
      (select min(RemovedDate)
         from table_2
        where Name=q1.Name
          and RemovedDate >= t1.AddedDate) as RemovedDate
 from table_1 t1
order by AddedDate desc,
         Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use left join on name

```
  select t1.name, t1.AddedDate, t2.RemovedDate
  from table1 t1 
  left join table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name 
  order by name, t1.AddedDate, t2.RemovedDate
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server Use the below script

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T1.Name ORDER BY T1.AddedDate DESC,T2.RemovedDate DESC)
        T1.Name,
        T1.AddedDate,
        T2.RemovedDate
        FROM Table1 T1 
            LEFT JOIN Table2 T2
                ON LTRIM(RTRIM(T1.name)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(T2.name))
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
    WHERE SeqNo = 1
```

If you want all the records for a Name, such as if a name was added and removed multiple times and you want each of the dates, then just execute without the

```
WHERE SeqNo = 1
```

part